# How to search activity location without % being added?

Tags: advanced-search

In several places, and specifically, the "location" field of an activity, as searched using the Advanced Search, I've noticed that given `hello there` CiviCRM will actually search on `%hello there%`.

Is it possible to make it just search on what was provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under admin - customize data and screens - search preferences, there's an option for automatic wildcard.

It seems to still wildcard the end of the search string, but not the beginning.

That admin page explains it:

> If enabled, wildcards are automatically added to the beginning AND end of the search term when users search for contacts by Name. EXAMPLE: Searching for 'ada' will return any contact whose name includes those letters - e.g. 'Adams, Janet', 'Nadal, Jorge', etc. If disabled, a wildcard is added to the end of the search term only. EXAMPLE: Searching for 'ada' will return any contact whose last name begins with those letters - e.g. 'Adams, Janet' but NOT 'Nadal, Jorge'. Disabling this feature will speed up search significantly for larger databases, but users must manually enter wildcards ('%' or '_') to the beginning of the search term if they want to find all records which contain those letters. EXAMPLE: '%ada' will return 'Nadal, Jorge'.

Comment: Yes - this is not consistent across fields but it *should* prepend a wild card unless that setting is disabled. On larger sites turning it off gives a big performance boost

Comment: Hey thanks, that's handy. And yes, it's a big performance problem because a prepended `%` means it can't use the index (which I've manually added). I feel a gitlab discussion coming on about this when I have the energy!